# PDB won't stop inside pytest code, will stop in first function call

Tags: python, pytest, pdb

If I define a pytest test like so:

```
from my_app.main import some_function

def test_example():
    breakpoint()
    foo = 'bar'
    some_function()
```

Then pdf will stop at the beginning of `some_function` instead of at `foo = 'bar'`. How can I get it to stop inside the test code?

Here is how I am running pytest:

```
pytest /app/tests/test_example.py::test_example --cov=/app/src/
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some PyTest plugins can interfere with pdb. Removing the `--cov` flag fixed the issue and I am now able to stop on breakpoints inside tests.

```
pytest /app/tests/test_example.py::test_example
```